# Observable if the array element is changed

Tags: c#, system.reactive

How I can write this code with a single line?

```
public class RadGridColumnObservable
{
    public RadGridColumnObservable(RadGridView grid, IMessageBus messageBus)
    {
        this.grid = grid;
        this.messageBus = messageBus;
    }

    public IDisposable Initialize()
    {
        CreateStates();

        return Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            .Subscribe(_ => CheckUp());
    }

    //

    private readonly RadGridView grid;
    private readonly IMessageBus messageBus;
    private readonly List<bool> states = new List<bool>();

    //

    private void CreateStates()
    {
        states.Clear();
        states.AddRange(grid.Columns.Select(it => it.IsVisible));
    }

    private void CheckUp()
    {
        if (states.SequenceEqual(grid.Columns.Select(it => it.IsVisible))) return;

        CreateStates();
        messageBus.Publish(new NotifyMessage(MessageTypes.HistoryColumnsChanged));
    }
}
```

The idea is: I want to check if the `IsVisible` property is changed.

I don't like to use this line:

```
private readonly List<bool> states = new List<bool>();
```

Comment: "isVisible" changed regarding what value? you need some structure to keep values to compare

Comment: I don't found any event for RadGridView when i hide/show columns, and i use a thread to compare old columns with the new columns to see when the "IsVisible" is changed. The code working ok , but i wana to optimize this with Observable.

Comment: The grid you're working with, is it a UI grid? If so, you'll need to do an `ObserveOn` to prevent threading issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can adjust your `Initialize()` to something like this:

```
public IDisposable Initialize()
{
    return Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .Select(v => grid.Columns.Select(it => it.IsVisible).ToList())
        .Scan((prev: new List<bool>(), actual: new List<bool>()),
            (acc, c) => (acc.actual, c))
        .Where(it => !it.actual.SequenceEqual(it.prev))
        .Subscribe(_ => messageBus.Publish(new NotifyMessage(MessageTypes.HistoryColumnsChanged)));
}
```

This should give you the same result and you only need `SequenceEqual()` once. The scan is just there so you have the "current" and the "previous" value. You don't really need to do a check inside it in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You could get your `IsVisible` values with something like this:

```
private IObservable<List<bool>> CreateStatesObservable()
{
    return Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                        .Select(_ => grid.Columns.Select(it => it.IsVisible));
}
```

And then use [Scan](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/scan.html) to keep track of your previous value:

```
public void Initialize()
{
    var observable = 
            CreateStatesObservable()
                        .Scan(
                            (prev: default(List<bool>), actual: default(List<bool>)),
                            (acc, c) => (acc.actual, current))
                        .Where(values => !values.actual.SequenceEqual(values.prev))
                        .Select(_ => true);
}
```

Or you could use [Defer](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/defer.html) and do something like this:

```
public void Initialize2()
{
    var observable = CreateStatesObservable();

    var deferred =
        Observable.Defer(
                      () =>
                      {
                          List<bool> previous = null;

                          return observable.Select(
                              values =>
                              {
                                  if (previous is null)
                                  {
                                      previous = values;
                                      return false;
                                  }

                                  if (!values.SequenceEqual(previous))
                                  {
                                      previous = values;
                                      return true;
                                  }

                                  return false;
                              });
                      })
                  .Where(value => value);
}
```

Both options should give you an observable which only produces a value when one of the columns `IsVisible` has changed. (That value just being a `true`)

**Edit:**

You can also use `DistinctUntilChanged()` with your own `IEqualityComparer` like this:

```
class ListComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<bool>>
{
    bool IEqualityComparer<List<bool>>.Equals(List<bool>? a, List<bool>? b)
    {
        if (a is null && b is null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        
        if (a is null || b is null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        
        return a.SequenceEqual(b);
    }

    int IEqualityComparer<List<bool>>.GetHashCode(List<bool> obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
public void Initialize()
{
    var observable = 
            CreateStatesObservable()
                        .DistinctUntilChanged(new ListComparer())
                        .Select(_ => true);
}
```

Comment: Very nice answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Happy to help :). Now that i think about it again you could maybe also get something to work with `DistinctUntilChanged()` and writing your own equality comparer implementing `IEqualityComparer<List<bool>>`

Comment: I updated my answer with an example for `DistinctUntilChanged()`

Comment: +1 I use the method with scan , i tested and Observable.Defer and working good. But the scan method i think is better. I'm beginner with system.reactive, but I really like the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I use now something like this:

```
public class RadGridColumnObservable
{
    public RadGridColumnObservable(RadGridView grid, IMessageBus messageBus)
    {
        this.grid = grid;
        this.messageBus = messageBus;
    }

    public IDisposable Initialize()
    {
        return Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            .Scan((prev: grid.Columns.Select(it => it.IsVisible).ToList(), actual: grid.Columns.Select(it => it.IsVisible).ToList()),
                (acc, c) =>
                {
                    if (!acc.prev.SequenceEqual(acc.actual))
                        acc.prev = acc.actual;

                    acc.actual = grid.Columns.Select(it => it.IsVisible).ToList();
                    return acc;
                })
            .Where(it => !it.prev.SequenceEqual(it.actual))
            .Subscribe(it => messageBus.Publish(new NotifyMessage(MessageTypes.HistoryColumnsChanged)));
    }

    //

    private readonly RadGridView grid;
    private readonly IMessageBus messageBus;
}
```

but i don't like because i use 2nd time "SequenceEqual".